# Shared cache between workers in Cloudhub?

Tags: caching, mule, mule-component, cloudhub, mule-cluster

From what I see in the [official cache scope documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/cache-scope#object-stores-and-clustering), if managed-object-store is used with appropriate values - cache is supposed to be shared between multiple workers/nodes in Cloudhub.

```
<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Caching_Strategy" keyGenerationExpression="#[flowVars.address_id + flowVars.count]" doc:name="Caching Strategy">
        <managed-store storeName="CacheStore" persistent="true" maxEntries="${cache.max.entries}" entryTTL="${cache.ttl}" expirationInterval="${cache.expiration.poll}"/>
</ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
```

But this is not working as expected. **The cache entries aren't being shared.** Each worker/node seems to creating its on cache store.

I tried a few combinations like making store persistent or decreasing expirationPoll to a few millis or making queues persistent and so on. No joy.

Your help is much appreciated.

Using **Mule Runtime 3.8.4**.

Comment: Are they deployed as separate applications in Cloudhub?

Comment: No @RyanCarter, they are deployed on 2 workers (Cloudhub Fabric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cache Scope` is designed to be used per worker and only as side cache pattern. For shared cache you'd need to for some kind of cluster cache solution. We eneded up going with `Hazelcast`.